# IIS and and Websites - Possible to use wild cards in a URL to get a listing of objects

Tags: iis, web-server, url

Is it possible to use wild cards in a URL to retrieve multiple objects located on a server, or a listing of multiple objects located on a server.

For example:

www.mywebsite.com/images/october/*.jpg

Or is there anything similar that would produce the result that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only possible if you have a custom developed filter, handler, or application that can understand the wildcard syntax.  IIS does not natively support wildcards in URLs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (at least in common HTTP 1.1), because the HTTP protocol doesn't work this way. For every HTTP request there is one HTTP response - the two together are called a HTTP transaction.

```
CLIENT --> HTTP Request  --> SERVER
CLIENT <-- HTTP Response <-- SERVER
CLIENT --> HTTP Request  --> SERVER
CLIENT <-- HTTP Response <-- SERVER
```

As workaround you could implement some sort of zip file where you collect all the files and return it as single file download.

Another approach would be a client-side (browser) implementation in JavaScript where you get the files in some sort of loop.

Both alternatives are rather theoretical solutions.